# Atom: How to escape the ! symbol in apm config proxy setting command?

Tags: atom-editor

**Issue**

Atom's apm cli command removes the following **!@host** from proxy string.

**Details**

apm config set http-proxy https://userid:pwd@host:port

example:

apm config set http-proxy https://mickeym:secret!@host:port

apm config get http-proxy ==  https://mickym:secret:port

**apm config set** command removes the  !(bang), @ and host character from the proxy setting making it impossible to use the proxy.

I tried escaping the ! with \ (backslash) symbol, but it did not work.  I confirmed that it is indeed the ! symbol causing the issue, by removing it from the string and being able to successfully add the proxy setting string.

Expected

https://mickeym:secret!@host:port

I also tried to add the ! bang symbol as a unicode literal in the string but it does not translate \u021, \u0021, \0x21

apm config set http-proxy [https://mickeym:secret\u021@host:port](https://mickeym:secret%5Cu021@host:port)

output: [https://mickeym:secret\u021@host:port](https://mickeym:secret%5Cu021@host:port)  (no good)

Comment: Old installations of Atom allowed this, so something must have changed. My previous proxy setting had a ! and proxy was working.